# Anybody managed to run Linux and KVM Windows with a single passthrough graphics card?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, pci

I have a Ubuntu system that runs FreeNAS in a KVM with one SATA controller card as passthrough. Because of that I only have one PCIe slot on my motherboard that fits a graphic card. I would now like to also run a Windows KVM capable of running 3D CAD software that require a GPU.

I have read serveral entries that describe windows running in KVM using passthrough of a second graphic card. However I would like to run a different setup with only one graphic card:

- run main Linux headless without a graphics card (only when installing or maintaining attach to it)
- passthrough the single graphic card to the Windows KVM, also passthrough mouse/keyboard to Windows
- operate linux via ssh of alternatively install a No-Machine server and connect via that from Windows.

Is there some resource that would describe howto implement such a setup?
Has anybody tried it before? 
I guess the sequence would be something like:

- Install vnc server in linux, operate though the vnc server interface
- Add a GRUB boot setting that would leave the graphic card handled by vfio
- Reboot into headless and setup an autostarted Windows KVM with graphics card attached

Sounds doable (?) but I guess there are numerouse pitfalls and I dont want to risk my current setup...

Comment: How about getting an old PCI graphics card for €10 or something?

Comment: I have a GA-970A-DS3P card that has actually 2 legacy PCI ports and I was looking at a GRAFIK CLUB 3D RADEON 9250 that is still available. That would be a dual monitor solution. However I want to only have one graphics card.

Comment: Oh. You haven't actually tried to pass through the card yet? Can't you just SSH to the server to manage it, and run VNC inside the guest that's running on the card, after configuring it to always vfio, to manage the guest?

Comment: @dobey: I didnt start configuring the passthrough yet. I'm hoping for a writeup of someone that has done that before to skip the pitfalls that will appear on the way...

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [this tutorial](https://www.evonide.com/non-root-gpu-passthrough-setup/#QEMU_setup) I got AMD 5450 passthrough of primary 
graphics card (host runs headless) working with the below script.

- Doing the standard vfio preparation
- add `video=efifb:off` to cmdline otherwise efifb would grab the PCI bar before vfio.
- Guest UEFI (OVMF image from `apt-get install ovmf`)
- `-vga qlx` used and later qlx Monitor is disabled inside Windows (Display Settings)
- no romfiles for AMD 5450.

I also tried with a NVidia 710b, however whas permanently stuck with "Code 43".
Probably because romfiles are needed there when trying to passthrough the primary card.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

b=$(pwd)

passthrough=0
qxl=1
uefi=1
ovmf=0
net=0
while getopts "bpQUon" opt; do
  case $opt in
      p) passthrough=1 ;;
      Q) qxl=0 ;;
      U) uefi=0 ;;
      n) net=1 ;;
      o) ovmf=1 ;;
  esac
done

cp ${b}/uefi/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd .
OPTS=""
# Basic CPU settings.
OPTS="$OPTS -cpu host,kvm=off"
OPTS="$OPTS -smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1"
# Enable KVM full virtualization support.
OPTS="$OPTS -enable-kvm"
# Assign memory to the vm.
OPTS="$OPTS -m 4000"

# VFIO GPU and GPU sound passthrough.
if [ "$passthrough" == "1" ]; then
    #,multifunction=on,romfile=/mnt/nvidia_efi.rom" ,romfile=${b}/bioses/XFX.HD5450.1024.110612.rom
    #OPTS="$OPTS -device vfio-pci,host=05:00.0,multifunction=on,romfile=${b}/bioses/XFX.HD5450.1024.110612.rom"
    #,romfile=${b}/bioses/XFX.HD5450.1024.110612_1.rom
    OPTS="$OPTS -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,multifunction=on" 
    #,romfile=/mnt/data-n0/vms-win/romfile_radeon.bin
    #,romfile=/mnt/nvidia_efi.rom"
    OPTS="$OPTS -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.1"
fi

# Supply OVMF (general UEFI bios, needed for EFI boot support with GPT disks).
if [ "$uefi" == "1" ]; then
    if [ "$ovmf" == "0" ]; then
    OPTS="$OPTS -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=${b}/uefi/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd"
    OPTS="$OPTS -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=${b}/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd"
    else
    mkdir -p ${b}/hda-contents
    #OPTS="$OPTS -pflash ${b}/ovmf_pkg/OVMF.fd"
    OPTS="$OPTS -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=${b}/ovmf_pkg/OVMF.fd"
    OPTS="$OPTS -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=${b}/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd"
    fi
fi

# Load our created VM image as a harddrive.
OPTS="$OPTS -hda ${b}/win10_uefi_cpu_host_qemu_vm.qcow2"
# Load our OS setup image e.g. ISO file.

#OPTS="$OPTS -cdrom ${b}/windows_10.iso"
OPTS="$OPTS -cdrom ${b}/virtio-win-0.1.141.iso"

if [ "$qxl" == "1" ]; then
    # Use the following emulated video device (use none for disabled).
    OPTS="$OPTS -vga qxl"
else
    # Use an emulated video device (use none for disabled).
    #  -vga none -device qxl
    OPTS="$OPTS -vga none -device qxl "
fi

OPTS="$OPTS -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing "

# Redirect QEMU's console input and output.
OPTS="$OPTS -monitor stdio"

if [ "${net}" == "1" ]; then
    # Improve the network performance by utilizing virtio-net.
    OPTS="$OPTS -device virtio-net,netdev=net0,mac=de:ad:be:ef:33:4a"
    OPTS="$OPTS -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=vmtap0,script=./qemu-ifup,downscript=./qemu-ifdown"
else
    OPTS="$OPTS -net none "
fi

#Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
#Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub

# USB mouse
if [ "$passthrough" == "1" ]; then
    OPTS="$OPTS -usb"
    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-ehci,id=ehci"
    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=usb-bus.0,vendorid=0x17ef,productid=0x6019 "
    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=usb-bus.0,vendorid=0x1c4f,productid=0x0002 "
fi
#if [ "$passthrough" == "1" ]; then
#    OPTS="$OPTS -usb"
#    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-ehci,id=ehci"
#    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=usb-bus.0,vendorid=0x17ef,productid=0x6019 "
#    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=usb-bus.0,vendorid=0x1c4f,productid=0x0002 "
#fi

#OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,hostbus=3,hostaddr=4"
#OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,hostbus=3,hostaddr=2"

#OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,vendorid=0x1c4f,productid=0x0002 "
#OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,vendorid=0x1a40,productid=0x0201 "

#OPTS="$OPTS -usbdevice host:1c4f:0002"
# USB keyboard
#OPTS="$OPTS -usbdevice host:1a40:0201"

sudo qemu-system-x86_64 $OPTS
```