# Passthrough of Radeon 5450 to windows cannot allocate resources

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, pci

I try to passthrough a Radeon 5450 GPU to a Win 7 guest from a Ubuntu 18.04 hots. I'm using machine type [q35](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Q35) when creating the VM with 
virt-manager because I read that 
it should be better for passthrough. When using the default 
pc-i440fx-bionic machine type the graphics driver would crash. When using q35 it doesn't crash but the driver cannot allocate resources.

Below is the machine definition.

I have the card at 05:00.0:

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
```

When I install the AMD driver ([catalyst](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%207%20-%2064)) the driver installs,
however it cannot allocate the IO ranges and IRQ's:

```
This device cannot find enough free resources that is can use (Code 12)
```

[image: not enough resources]

What is wrong with my definition?

```
<domain type='kvm' id='12'>
  <name>win7-2</name>
  <uuid>ae01eb73-b725-4abb-9ce2-d544393de40e</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8290304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8290304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-2.11'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>Opteron_G5</model>
    <feature policy='require' name='vme'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='x2apic'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='rdtscp'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/mnt/data-n0/vm/win7-passthrough.img'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <alias name='sata0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/mnt/data-n0/vm/SW.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='sata0-0-1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'>
      <alias name='pcie.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='dmi-to-pci-bridge'>
      <model name='i82801b11-bridge'/>
      <alias name='pci.1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1e' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pci-bridge'>
      <model name='pci-bridge'/>
      <target chassisNr='2'/>
      <alias name='pci.2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x10'/>
      <alias name='pci.3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x11'/>
      <alias name='pci.4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x12'/>
      <alias name='pci.5'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x13'/>
      <alias name='pci.6'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:5d:59:31'/>
      <source bridge='br1'/>
      <target dev='vnet2'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/5'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/5'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/5'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='spice' port='5903' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <driver name='vfio'/>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <alias name='hostdev0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir1'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='apparmor' relabel='yes'>
    <label>libvirt-ae01eb73-b725-4abb-9ce2-d544393de40e</label>
    <imagelabel>libvirt-ae01eb73-b725-4abb-9ce2-d544393de40e</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+64055:+131</label>
    <imagelabel>+64055:+131</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Comment: The card is not your only GPU in the system, is it?

Comment: @dobey : Yes, it is the only GPU in the system. I have blacklisted it in the linux host and running the host headless. I think you relied to my other thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064242/anybody-managed-to-run-linux-and-kvm-windows-with-a-single-passthrough-graphics

Comment: @dodey: Maybe I should skip the Radeon 5450 and buy a newer one. But then the question is which one is best suited for passthrough (should also be not expensive).

Comment: I don't know. AFAIK this should work as you have it. Perhaps the problem is related to the other two PCI devices with warning icons in device manager? Have you installed the RH VirtIO drivers package in the guest?

Comment: I can try that.

Comment: i installed RH ballon and serial driver, but it is the same.

Comment: Did you install the AMD Catalyst driver package for Windows?

Comment: Of course. I tried with the autodetect, the catalyst and also the one downloaded by driver update.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [this tutorial](https://www.evonide.com/non-root-gpu-passthrough-setup/#QEMU_setup) I got AMD 5450 passthrough of primary 
graphics card (host runs headless) working with the below script.

- Guest UEFI (OVMF image from `apt-get install ovmf`)
- `-vga qlx` used and later qlx Monitor is disabled inside Windows (Display Settings)
- add `video=efifb:off` to cmdline otherwise efifb would grab the PCI bar before vfio.
- no romfiles needed for AMD 5450 if running that way (with `-vga qlx`)

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

b=$(pwd)

passthrough=0
qxl=1
uefi=1
ovmf=0
net=0
while getopts "bpQUon" opt; do
  case $opt in
      p) passthrough=1 ;;
      Q) qxl=0 ;;
      U) uefi=0 ;;
      n) net=1 ;;
      o) ovmf=1 ;;
  esac
done

cp ${b}/uefi/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd .
OPTS=""
# Basic CPU settings.
OPTS="$OPTS -cpu host,kvm=off"
OPTS="$OPTS -smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1"
# Enable KVM full virtualization support.
OPTS="$OPTS -enable-kvm"
# Assign memory to the vm.
OPTS="$OPTS -m 4000"

# VFIO GPU and GPU sound passthrough.
if [ "$passthrough" == "1" ]; then
    #,multifunction=on,romfile=/mnt/nvidia_efi.rom" ,romfile=${b}/bioses/XFX.HD5450.1024.110612.rom
    #OPTS="$OPTS -device vfio-pci,host=05:00.0,multifunction=on,romfile=${b}/bioses/XFX.HD5450.1024.110612.rom"
    #,romfile=${b}/bioses/XFX.HD5450.1024.110612_1.rom
    OPTS="$OPTS -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,multifunction=on" 
    #,romfile=/mnt/data-n0/vms-win/romfile_radeon.bin
    #,romfile=/mnt/nvidia_efi.rom"
    OPTS="$OPTS -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.1"
fi

# Supply OVMF (general UEFI bios, needed for EFI boot support with GPT disks).
if [ "$uefi" == "1" ]; then
    if [ "$ovmf" == "0" ]; then
    OPTS="$OPTS -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=${b}/uefi/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd"
    OPTS="$OPTS -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=${b}/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd"
    else
    mkdir -p ${b}/hda-contents
    #OPTS="$OPTS -pflash ${b}/ovmf_pkg/OVMF.fd"
    OPTS="$OPTS -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=${b}/ovmf_pkg/OVMF.fd"
    OPTS="$OPTS -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=${b}/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd"
    fi
fi

# Load our created VM image as a harddrive.
OPTS="$OPTS -hda ${b}/win10_uefi_cpu_host_qemu_vm.qcow2"
# Load our OS setup image e.g. ISO file.

#OPTS="$OPTS -cdrom ${b}/windows_10.iso"
OPTS="$OPTS -cdrom ${b}/virtio-win-0.1.141.iso"

if [ "$qxl" == "1" ]; then
    # Use the following emulated video device (use none for disabled).
    OPTS="$OPTS -vga qxl"
else
    # Use an emulated video device (use none for disabled).
    #  -vga none -device qxl
    OPTS="$OPTS -vga none -device qxl "
fi

OPTS="$OPTS -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing "

# Redirect QEMU's console input and output.
OPTS="$OPTS -monitor stdio"

if [ "${net}" == "1" ]; then
    # Improve the network performance by utilizing virtio-net.
    OPTS="$OPTS -device virtio-net,netdev=net0,mac=de:ad:be:ef:33:4a"
    OPTS="$OPTS -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=vmtap0,script=./qemu-ifup,downscript=./qemu-ifdown"
else
    OPTS="$OPTS -net none "
fi

#Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
#Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub

# USB mouse
if [ "$passthrough" == "1" ]; then
    OPTS="$OPTS -usb"
    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-ehci,id=ehci"
    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=usb-bus.0,vendorid=0x17ef,productid=0x6019 "
    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=usb-bus.0,vendorid=0x1c4f,productid=0x0002 "
fi
#if [ "$passthrough" == "1" ]; then
#    OPTS="$OPTS -usb"
#    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-ehci,id=ehci"
#    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=usb-bus.0,vendorid=0x17ef,productid=0x6019 "
#    OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=usb-bus.0,vendorid=0x1c4f,productid=0x0002 "
#fi

#OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,hostbus=3,hostaddr=4"
#OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,hostbus=3,hostaddr=2"

#OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,vendorid=0x1c4f,productid=0x0002 "
#OPTS="$OPTS -device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,vendorid=0x1a40,productid=0x0201 "

#OPTS="$OPTS -usbdevice host:1c4f:0002"
# USB keyboard
#OPTS="$OPTS -usbdevice host:1a40:0201"

sudo qemu-system-x86_64 $OPTS
```